# How to use Activator.CreateInstance with List<T> when Deserialize json with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, list, windows-phone-7, activator, deserialization

I'm deserializing this json string:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
```

The class which represents the items is:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass 
{

        public MyClass() {
            this._dtcreate = new DateTime();
        }

        private int _id;
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id {get;set;}

        private DateTime _dtcreate;
}
```

Note that in the default constructor of MyClass I set a default value for "_dtcreate".

So, I'm using this code to Deserialize json into a Array of T:

```
 public static T[] DeserializeArray<T>(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T[]));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
        T[] gType = (T[])ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return gType;
    }
```

When I deserialize a json string I not found in my deserialized array the property "_dtcreate" evalued.

I think DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't use the default constructor of MyClass.

Can I use the

```
T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

to create an instance for all object belonging to the array "gType" to make me ensure that all objects of my list deserialiced are created with the dafault constructor of my T class ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `DateTime` is a struct.  Your constructor is completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataContract serializers will not run constructors.

Instead, you should put your logic into [an `[OnDeserializing]` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I set this._dtcreate = new DateTime(); in the OnDeserializedMethod and work fine..

Comment: @Nicola: You don't need to do that at all.  Since DateTime is a value type, it will be automatically set to its default value.  It cannot be `null`.  You might be looking for for `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: The property "_dtcreate" is just an example. I really have a string property to set with a default value. Thank you for support!